# MySQL replication ignoring BINLOG statements for certain table

Tags: mysql, mysql-replication

I'm trying to make MySQL Replication work, but my slave is constantly stopping because of constraint fails.

This errors occurs because the replication of one particular table is not working.

If I check the Relay Log File, I can see several BINLOG statements that should be inserting rows to that table, but they don't. Here's an example:

```
BINLOG '
sQn+VBMLAAAAYQAAAOkmaCUAAOnamUgBAAEADWRtXzc1NF9kYmJ1ZDkACnBlcnNvbmFzX18AEgMD
AwP+Dw8PDw8P/g/+AQcDART3AZYAlgBaACwBAwA8APcBPAD3AQ5+Ag==
sQn+VBcLAAAAWwAAAEQnaCUAAOnamUgBAAEAEv///w56/AEAAAADCHJlaW5hbGRvA2dvbgASAHJl
eWdvbmNsQGdtYWlsLmNvbQg5MTkwNzAzNrEJ/lQBAAAAAA==
'/*!*/;
### INSERT INTO `dm_754_dbbud9`.`personas__`
### SET
###   @1=1 /* INT meta=0 nullable=0 is_null=0 */
###   @2=NULL /* INT meta=0 nullable=1 is_null=1 */
###   @3=NULL /* INT meta=0 nullable=1 is_null=1 */
###   @4=NULL /* INT meta=0 nullable=1 is_null=1 */
###   @5=3 /* ENUM(1 byte) meta=63233 nullable=0 is_null=0 */
###   @6='reinaldo' /* VARSTRING(150) meta=150 nullable=0 is_null=0 */
###   @7='gon' /* VARSTRING(150) meta=150 nullable=0 is_null=0 */
###   @8='' /* VARSTRING(90) meta=90 nullable=0 is_null=0 */
###   @9='xxxxxx@gmail.com' /* VARSTRING(300) meta=300 nullable=0 is_null=0 */
###   @10=NULL /* VARSTRING(300) meta=3 nullable=1 is_null=1 */
###   @11='91907036' /* VARSTRING(60) meta=60 nullable=1 is_null=0 */
###   @12=NULL /* VARSTRING(60) meta=63233 nullable=1 is_null=1 */
###   @13=NULL /* VARSTRING(60) meta=60 nullable=1 is_null=1 */
###   @14=NULL /* VARSTRING(60) meta=63233 nullable=1 is_null=1 */
###   @15=NULL /* VARSTRING(60) meta=0 nullable=1 is_null=1 */
###   @16=1425934769 /* TIMESTAMP meta=0 nullable=0 is_null=0 */
###   @17=1 /* INT meta=0 nullable=0 is_null=0 */
###   @18=0 /* TINYINT meta=0 nullable=1 is_null=0 */
```

When executing those lines on a mysql terminal, no error is printed, but also, no row is inserted.

All other tables seem to be working fine.

Any ideas of what could be wrong?

**EDIT**: this is the slave stauts:

```
               Slave_IO_State: Waiting for master to send event
                  Master_Host: 127.0.0.1
                  Master_User: replicacionusr
                  Master_Port: 33061
                Connect_Retry: 60
              Master_Log_File: servidor-bin.000005
          Read_Master_Log_Pos: 38324143
               Relay_Log_File: mysqld-relay-bin.000012
                Relay_Log_Pos: 345615012
        Relay_Master_Log_File: servidor-bin.000004
             Slave_IO_Running: Yes
            Slave_SQL_Running: No
              Replicate_Do_DB: 
          Replicate_Ignore_DB: 
           Replicate_Do_Table: 
       Replicate_Ignore_Table: 
      Replicate_Wild_Do_Table: 
  Replicate_Wild_Ignore_Table: %.sesiones_usuarios__%
                   Last_Errno: 1452
               Last_Error: Error 'Cannot add or update a child row: a foreign key constraint fails (`dm_752_dbnor1`.`recursos__`, CONSTRAINT `recursos___ibfk_1` FOREIGN KEY (`id_usuario_creo`) REFERENCES `usuarios__` (`id_usuario`))' on query. Default database: 'dm_752_dbnor1'. Query: 'INSERT INTO recursos__ (id_recurso,id_usuario_encargado,id_usuario_creo,tipo,activo,fecha_creacion,version,eliminado) VALUES (NULL,NULL,1,'sucursal',1,'2015-    03-09 18:00:53',1,0)'
                 Skip_Counter: 0
          Exec_Master_Log_Pos: 627770120
              Relay_Log_Space: 830068736
              Until_Condition: None
               Until_Log_File: 
                Until_Log_Pos: 0
           Master_SSL_Allowed: No
           Master_SSL_CA_File: 
           Master_SSL_CA_Path: 
              Master_SSL_Cert: 
            Master_SSL_Cipher: 
               Master_SSL_Key: 
        Seconds_Behind_Master: NULL
Master_SSL_Verify_Server_Cert: No
                Last_IO_Errno: 0
                Last_IO_Error: 
               Last_SQL_Errno: 1452
           Last_SQL_Error: Error 'Cannot add or update a child row: a foreign key constraint fails (`dm_752_dbnor1`.`recursos__`, CONSTRAINT `recursos___ibfk_1` FOREIGN KEY (`id_usuario_creo`) REFERENCES `usuarios__` (`id_usuario`))' on query. Default database: 'dm_752_dbnor1'. Query: 'INSERT INTO recursos__ (id_recurso,id_usuario_encargado,id_usuario_creo,tipo,activo,fecha_creacion,version,eliminado) VALUES (NULL,NULL,1,'sucursal',1,'2015-03-09 18:00:53',1    ,0)'
  Replicate_Ignore_Server_Ids: 
             Master_Server_Id: 11
```

Comment: Is this specific table replicated too? What's the slave status?

Comment: The table structure is being replicated. I have edited my question to add the slave status

Comment: Did you try an insert from the mysql client on the server; so `use dm_754_dbbud9`, then `insert into personas__ ...`? Is this replicated? `use` can be tricky.

Comment: Yes. If I run `use ...` and then `insert ...` I'm able to execute the statement and the row is created, however, if I run `use ...` and then `binlog ...` nothing happens

Comment: So it is created only on the master, it appears in the binlog, but not in the slaves table? And the slave status stays ok?

Comment: It is inserted on the master, but not the slave. For that particular statement the slave status stays ok, but future statements that insert rows in tables which are related with the problematic one fail (constraint not met) so the slave gets stopped

Comment: Could you just see what happens, if you omit `Replicate_Wild_Ignore_Table: %.sesiones_usuarios__%`?

Comment: I just tried, but the problem is still there. What I'm executing is `mysql> BINLOG 'sQn+VBMLAAAAYQAAAOkmaCUAAOnamUgBAAEADWRtXzc1NF9kYmJ1ZDkACnBlcnNvbmFzX18AEgMD
AwP+Dw8PDw8P/g/+AQcDART3AZYAlgBaACwBAwA8APcBPAD3AQ5+Ag==
sQn+VBcLAAAAWwAAAEQnaCUAAOnamUgBAAEAEv///w56/AEAAAADCHJlaW5hbGRvA2dvbgASAHJleWdvbmNsQGdtYWlsLmNvbQg5MTkwNzAzNrEJ/lQBAAAAAA==';`  and the result is `Query OK, 0 rows affected (0.00 sec)`

The statement is executed, but the row is not inserted in the table personas__

Answer (score 0):

This is the error as it is in the show slave status output:

> Last_Error: Error 'Cannot add or update a child row: a foreign key
>   constraint fails (`dm_752_dbnor1`.`recursos__`, CONSTRAINT
>   `recursos___ibfk_1` FOREIGN KEY (`id_usuario_creo`) REFERENCES
>   `usuarios__` (`id_usuario`))' on query. Default database:
>   'dm_752_dbnor1'. Query: 'INSERT INTO recursos__
>   (id_recurso,id_usuario_encargado,id_usuario_creo,tipo,activo,fecha_creacion,version,eliminado)
>   VALUES (NULL,NULL,1,'sucursal',1,'2015-    03-09 18:00:53',1,0)'

you have to check why this fails first.